# 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am a newbie and just created a new project of type: ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) and let VS preload all the defaults.  I changed nothing, except set index.cshtml the startup.  It built ok, but has a run-time error of:

```
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Call Stack (last item):

```
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject() Unknown
```

What is happening here, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: are you sure you have the latest version of vs2017 and the .net core sdk installed?

Comment: Did you create a .NET Core or a .NET application? If Core, there might be some problem in your .NET Core Runtime

Comment: If a simple dotnet restore --no-cache isn't working then I would suggest you trying updating / reinstalling .net core runtime and tooling as well as VS. Make sure you have the latest versions as Joe said.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone.  I tried a few things, it was the Repair that worked at the end.  To answer the questions, yes it was a .NET Core applicaiton, but no vs2017 was not up-to-date, so I first tried an update, but problem still persisted.

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio Installer, selecting the Repair option solved the problem.